# Changing window order in multi-form application

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I have an application with some non-modal forms and each with its own icon. I need the icons of all forms on the taskbar that don't disappear on minimize/restore and after some testing, this is my solution.

**Application**

```
Application.Initialize;
Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
Application.Run;
```

**TForm1** - Main form with one `TButton`

```
procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TForm2.Create(Application).Show;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_APPWINDOW);
  Application.OnRestore := FormShow;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowWindow(Application.Handle, SW_HIDE);
end;
```

**TForm2**

```
procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetWindowLong(Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_APPWINDOW);
end;
```

This will create 2 icons on taskbar and 2 windows in <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, both working as expected, except one thing...switching application moves all previous application windows before the current application window, not just one window.

For example, my application has main form and other non-modal form. If I'm in Google Chrome and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, then this will appper, which is fine.

[image]

But this will move all of my application windows before Google Chrome and on next <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> I see this, so I have to press<kbd>Alt</kbd> + 2x <kbd>Tab</kbd> to get back to the Chrome.

[image]

I would like to achieve this behavior as if I had more applications and not one with multiple windows.

[image]

I'm not sure how exactly it works, but I assume there are multiple lists in the background, one for all applications and one for the windows of the application, so when I switch the application, it moves in the list before the previous one and therefore all of its windows.

If this is how it works, is there an option to switch applications and not just windows? If not, is it possible to change the behavior to not move all the windows but only one active window or my whole process is wrong and the same effect can be achieved different way, where it works as it should?

Comment: How did you create these windows? Did you specify an owner?

Comment: `TForm.Create(Application)`, but I don't think that owner would change something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that I understand your problem better, the problem is that `TApplication` also has a window and plays a role in the behaviour that you see.
The solution is rather simple, make sure that ALL your top level windows have `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` EXCEPT `TApplication`. The second problem is that TApplication is the parent of these windows, not the desktop so you need to specify this.

Form1:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
  strict protected
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
  public
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
  Unit2;

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;
  Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_EX_APPWINDOW;
  // make desktop the owner, not the TApplication window
  Params.WndParent := GetDesktopWindow;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 SetWindowLong(Application.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE,  GetWindowLong(Application.Handle,GWL_EXSTYLE) and not WS_EX_APPWINDOW or WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW);
 Form2 := TForm2.Create(Application);
 Form2.Show;
end;

end.
```

Form2:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
  strict protected
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TForm2 }

procedure TForm2.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;
  Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_EX_APPWINDOW;
  // make desktop the owner, not the TApplication window
  Params.WndParent := GetDesktopWindow;
end;

end.
```